# podPress and nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, podpress

Since we moved our server to a nginx-based environment, the permalinks of the podPress stopped working:

e.g.: http://www.tecnoblog.net/podpress_trac/web/113765/0/TBPod021.mp3

The nginx appears to search for the `.mp3` file rather than process the request using index.php.

Someone has a insight of what I could do? Some config to let `index.php` treat the request?

Comment: What did you do to configure nginx for pretty URLs? Have you read through http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx ?

Comment: I configure for Wordpress (basically try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;). But when the url is a file (like .mp3) nginx looks for the file instead of executing index.php

Comment: Sure that is what `try_files` is for. You need to deal with the mp3 upload folder location first and differently. There if the file exists, you want to re-write it to `index.php`. But you can not do that with `try_files` alone.

Comment: Can u pst your complete config? Look for a `location{}` block which might be intercepting mp3 requests. Generally for the purpose of browser caching!